# Select a subsequence of a sequence according to tosses of a biased coin

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, random, sampling

I have a sequence, from which I would like to select a subsequence, each term of the original sequence being included in the subsequence with probability $p$, independently of the other terms. That is, for each term in the sequence, I toss a biased coin to decide whether or not to keep it.

My question is whether there is a more elegant or more efficient way to do it, than this ?

```
list = {a, b, b, c, d, e, e, e, f, g};
p = 1/3;
Map[Part[list, #] &, Flatten[Position[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], Length[list]], 1]]]
```

A typical output is:

```
{b, e, e}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = 1/3;

SeedRandom[1]
Pick[list, RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], Length[list]], 1]
```

> ```
> {a, b, g}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
Extract[list, Position[1]@RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], Length[list]]]
```

> ```
> {a, b, g}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
list[[Flatten@Position[1]@RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], Length[list]]]]
```

> ```
>  {a, b, g}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
list[[PositionIndex[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], Length[list]]]@1]]
```

> ```
> {a, b, g}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much ! What a lot of nice solutions from which to choose ! I will use your first one :)

Comment: A bit shorter: `Pick[list, RandomChoice[{2/3, 1/3} -> {0, 1}, Length@list], 1]`.